# How do I better retain more advanced German words?

Tags: vocabulary

I am finding it hard to remember my vocabulary words for a longer period of time and wanted to know if there are any tips on retention in relations to German.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After having learnt a great deal of grammar and being confident at speaking what I know, how do I go about expanding my vocabulary?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34245/after-having-learnt-a-great-deal-of-grammar-and-being-confident-at-speaking-what)

Comment: If you could tell us a bit more about your specific problems, and what sort of vocabulary you mean in particular, we could be more helpful to you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com

Comment: Use use use use use. Read. Speak. Write. Listen. (That's for German. I don't know for other languages. I have never tried learning one.)

Answer (score 7):

**Use** the language you want to learn!

There is no better way to remember what you have learned than using it.

You've learned how to ride a bicycle and wonder how to do it better? Reading a book about riding bikes will not help. Riding a bike will.

Have you heard of the man who became a well known pianist just by reading books about playing the piano? No? Well, nobody heard of him, because he doesn't exist. You can't become a good pianist without playing the piano again and again. Good pianists play the piano 10 hours a day. Every day. For decades.

And the very same is true for languages: Reading books about German grammar will turn you into a person who can make a good presentation about German grammar and learning vocabulary by heart will fill your brain with lots of new facts. But the effect on the ability to speak the new language is weak.

Speak German if you want to learn German! Write essays in German! When you are here on German.stackexchange: Do not ask your questions in English. Try to write your questions in German. If you make a mistake somebody will edit you post and correct your errors. Find a friend who speaks German and speak German with him or her. Spend your next holidays in Germany or Austria. If you come with your family, speak German with them. (I sometimes travel to London with my wife, and when we are there we do not speak German with each other. We speak English.) Watch movies in German language, read German newspapers and magazines.

If you're not so good at German, start with passively using the language, i.e. listening and reading. But begin as soon as possible also to use this language actively: write and speak German.

And don't worry about memorizing long lists of vocabulary. Nobody who speaks a language does this in real life. You just use the vocabulary that you have. And when the word you need to formulate the next idea won't pop up in your mind, use other words. Build new sentences. Describe what you want to say. This is how everybody else does too.

And do not worry about failing. Those who are good now (in whatever discipline you can think of) failed more often in the past than the average people ever tried.

Comment: A very good answer. I'd like to add another little thing: Find an internet message board in German that covers an interest or hobby that you have. Become a member and participate.

Comment: Most effective method of course: find a German speaking boyfriend/girlfriend and live with him/her. (In extension of Hubert's good advice.)

Comment: Eine deutsche Liebschaft kann aber einen sehr eingeschränkten Wortschatz haben (tiefer, tiefer) oder verletzt/verstimmt reagieren, wenn sie erfährt, wegen ihres Wortschatzes ausgewählt worden zu sein. Zudem lernt man in der Liebe schnell von den Augen abzulesen, statt von den Lippen. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion: stop seeing them as "advanced" German words. There are no "simple" or "advanced" words in any language. Words represent ideas (or objects). It is your own attitude to these ideas or objects that makes you perceive them as "simple" or "advanced".

Comment: Bei der intendierten Realisierung der linguistischen Simplifizierung des regionalen Idioms resultiert die Evidenz der Opportunität extrem apparent, den elaborienten und quantitativ opulenten Usus nicht assimilierter Xenologien konsequent zu eliminieren. Judge for yourself if these are simple or advanced words. I agree with the essence of your post though, that one shouldn't be afraid of learning words that are thought of as difficult.

Comment: @infinitezero   Exactly as I said: If you are used to that sort of language, it is not "advanced" for you. Adult people do not learn languages necessarily like little children. They may start with other concepts in mind they want to speak about, and with a different vocabulary. - Moreover, one could claim that this of language is not advanced, rather retarded. :-|

Comment: You must agree, that there is an easier way to formulate my aforementioned sentence.

Answer (score -3):

Become a computer. Humans forget words if they don't use them. We tend to remember words if we *live* them, though, so human contact enhances your memory.

Comment: I'm sorry but I find this very incomprehensible. You might want to try deepL for a good translation service from e.g. German to English.

Comment: @infinitezero What precisely is very incomprehensible?

Comment: "Become a computer"? "We live words", "human contact enhance" is it meant as an imperative or is there just an s missing?

Comment: @infinitezero   Me as a human do understand all these phrases perfectly. - Are you perhaps a computer? (Okay, we should start now a debate about "what actually means 'understanding'?)

Comment: "Werde ein Computer?" Wie wird man ein Computer? Wir leben Worte? Was soll das bedeuten?

Comment: @infinitezero  Würdest du einen Satz wie "Lebe deine Träume" verstehen?

Comment: That's an idiom.

Comment: @infinitezero  It being an idiom does not make a difference here. In both cases the verb *leben* is used together with an accusative object - which is unusual anyway, as the basic use of *leben* is without an object. And if you understand "Lebe deine Träume", you are not far away from understanding "Lebe deine Worte". Träume are (more or less) complex concepts in your brain. Words are (more or less) complex concepts in your brain, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98626/discussion-between-infinitezero-and-christian-geiselmann).

Comment: Ja, lebe Deinen Sprachmüll, aber bitte nur in Deinen Träumen, nicht hier aus.

Comment: @userunknown Wo genau ist hier ein *Sprachmüll*? Du solltest nüchtern kommentieren.

Comment: Wörter leben, um sie zu lernen, ist Sprachmüll. Küchenmaschine, Kompetenzgerangel, Rassismus - soll man das leben, um die Wörter zu lernen? "Wir leben XY" ist Marketingsprache die einen totalitären Anspruch des Unternehmens auf seine Mitarbeiter formuliert - glücklicherweise steckt dann meist doch nichts Ernsthaftes dahinter, aber die Phantasie ist schon gruselig genug.

Comment: @userunknown  Man braucht nicht Rassismus zu üben, um das Wort *Rassismus* außerhalb der Wortschatzheften zu verwenden. Man kann Rassismus-Artikel lesen (das ist schon Praxis der Sprache), sich an Diskussionen beteiligen, usw. Küchenmaschine lernt man dadurch, dass man kocht, eine verwendet und alles in der Zielsprache denkt. So habe ich sieben Fremdsprachen gelernt. Die Methode kann vielleicht *dir* nichts nützen (weil etwa deine Lernprozesse wohl anders optimiert werden könnten) aber wieso ist das Müll?

Comment: Du hast aber geschrieben, man soll Wörter leben, nicht Artikel über Wörter lesen. Eine Küchenmaschine zu benutzen lernt man durch die Verwendung - dass ich, wenn ich Englisch lerne, durch Benutzung der Küchenmaschine das englische Wort für Knethaken lerne ist ein frommer Wunsch, mit "Küchenmaschine leben" sehe ich den Vorgang dennoch nicht beschrieben. Es ist einfach eine leere Floskel, frisch von Zombies auf dem evangelischen Kirchentag abgelauscht.

Comment: @userunknown Man lernt Knethaken daruch, dass man mit jemand in der Küche war, die/der das erwähnte. Garantiert bleibt das Wort im Gedächtnis länger als wenn man das Wort im Wörterbuch liest. Wenn du das bestreitest und Gegenteiliges beweist, dann ist meine tatsächlich eine leere Floskel.

Comment: @c.p.: Man kann nicht einen Knethaken leben, auch nicht einen Leberhaken oder eine Küchenmaschine, die Floskel ist so oder so ein Krampf. Eine Empfehlung Wörterbücher zu lesen habe ich nicht abgegeben, daher bin ich nicht zuständig dafür, eine solche zu verteidigen - Du unterliegst einer Black-White-Fallacy wenn Du meinst, dass das die einzig denkbare Alternative zum Leben von Begriffen sei. Wie soll man auch irgendwas leben, wenn man den Begriff nicht mal kennt? Literatur erfüllt auch oft die Funktion, einen in gänzlich fremde Welten zu entführen, Jahrhunderte, Landstriche, soziale Millieus…

Comment: @userunknown Lesen gehört zur „live words“-Sache.  Der ist auch keine Floskel denn, wie ich ja schon zeigte, Inhalt hat.  Man kennt gewissen Begriff, weil man etwas gelebt hat–nicht andersrum (ich sage ja nicht, dass man gezielt lebt um bestimmten Wortschatz zu lernen:). Man lernt  dadurch, dass man sich in die Zielsprache einbettet, d.h. man erlaubt sich nur Nachrichten, Gespräche, Zeitung, Partnerschaft, ja Gedanken (somit quasi das Leben selbst)  in der Zielsprache.

Comment: Du hast aber nicht geschrieben, dass wir Wörter lernen, in dem wir in einer Umgebung leben, wo sie verwendet werden, sondern dass wir uns an Wörter erinnern, wenn wir sie leben. Für ein konkretes Wort wie Rassismus bedeutet das, dass wir Rassismus leben müssten. Rassismus leben macht aber keinen Sinn. Rassismus ausleben gibt es. Etwas vorleben oder durchleben - aber für die meisten Wörter wie Müffelstück, marzipanartig oder minderbemittelt lässt sich beim besten Willen keine sinnvolle Interpretation finden.